# Unity Scene does not exist although its defined?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a death script for my game in Unity. I made a 3d Box without textures underneath my level and made its Collider `isTrigger = true`. I now added a script to the box that reloads the current scene when the player enters the trigger. Its 2 lines of code and I don't know why but I get the error:

```
Assets\scripts\death.cs(20,32): error CS0103: The name 'currentScene' does not exist in the current context
```

The Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class death : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
        Scene currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(currentScene.buildIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You defined the variable locally in `Start` - you have to make it a member of the class

Comment: Then i get the following error: UnityException: GetActiveScene is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start instead. Called from MonoBehaviour 'death' on game object 'death'.

Comment: You need to declare the variable as a member and assign the value in `Start`.... Also this is very basic C# knowledge, you should be going through a good tutorial instead of posting such basic questions here

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to add SOLVED or RESOLVED to your question title, or to edit a solution into the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the comments above already noticed your problem was the local variable and thanks to them, but this is just about to optimize your code and memory. you can just keep OnTriggerEnter only and delete Start.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
}
```

there's no need to store the scene in a variable if we will not use in a further needs. it will be just a waste of memory (bad habit)